# Is there any way to implement a taskGroup to run in parrarel inside another taskGroup?

Tags: swift

I am using Firebase to fetch some data from it with a Continuation. Before resuming the continuation I want to run a group of async tasks inside(fetch other data). This would let me achieve maximum concurrency.
I have tried two methods to do this, both does not work.

This is what I have tried first trying to use inside a continuation a taskGroup.(Code Below). The error is in comment.

## First Option

```
    try? await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
            for referencePosts in referencePostsDict.keys {
                group.addTask {
                    return try! await self.fetchPost(reference: referencePosts)
                }
            }
```

```
    func fetchPost(reference: String) async throws -> Void{
         var db_ref = Database.database(url:FIREBASEURL.url)
                      .reference()
                      .child("posts")
                      .child(reference)
        typealias postContinuation = CheckedContinuation<Void,Error>
        return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation{ 
               (continuation : postContinuation)  in

           db_ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { data in
                if data.exists(){
                    var three = data.value as! [String : Any]
                    withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in //async' call in a function that does not support concurrency 
                    (three["picturePaths"] as! [String : String]).forEach { key, value in
                          if key != "O"{
                             group.addTask {
                                try? await self.fetchPictureDataL(picRef: key)
                              }
                            self.threePictures[key] = value
                            }
                           }
                        }
                  
                    self.threePosts[reference] = three
                    continuation.resume(returning: ())
                }else{
                    continuation.resume(returning: ())
                }
            }
        }
}
```

```
         func fetchPictureDataL(picRef : String) async throws ->Void{
          var db =Database
          .database(url:FIREBASEURL.url)
          .reference()
          .child("pictures").child(picRef)
        typealias postContinuation = CheckedContinuation<Void,Error>
        return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation{ 
            (continuation : postContinuation) in
            db.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { data in
                self.threePicturesFetched[picRef] = three as! [String : Any]
                continuation.resume(returning: ())
            }
        }
    }
```

I commented the code where the compiler reports a problem.

## Second Option

### fetchCheckIn2 method is modified to return a [String]

This is the second method where I have tried to achieve the same result different, to mention the fetchCheckIn2 method is modified to return a [String].
What I want to achieve is that the fetchPictureDataL will run in parallel inside a Task or group, and will not run awaiting each other to finish.

```
                  //fetching all references
    try! await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: [String].self) { firstGroup in
        for referenceCheckIn in reference_checkInInt_dictionary.keys {
            firstGroup.addTask {
                return try await self.fetchCheckIn2(reference: referenceCheckIn)
            }
        }
        for try await pictureArray in firstGroup {
                    if pictureArray.count != 0 {
                        for pic in pictureArray {
                            try! await self.fetchPictureDataL(picRef: pic)
                        }
                    }
        }
    }
```

### Trying to achieve

I want to achieve parallelism even with fetchPictureDataL method?
If not clear why I am trying to do this, please read the use of case.

### Use of this case:

I have social media app with posts. I have a list of paths in order to fetch the post. Each post contains an array of other paths which are pictures.
I want to fetch posts parrarel and also fetch the pictures in parrarel, in a taskGruop, so all this fetch of post+picture is awaited and can be displayed to User.

### Thank you